# How to binding a optional type to non-optional type

Tags: ios, binding, swiftui, state, option-type

Xcode says Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'

```
struct CustomContentView: View {
    @State var queryItem = URLQueryItem.init(name: "key", value: nil)

    var body: some View {
//queryItem.value is optional string
        TextField.init("value", text: $queryItem.value)
//Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'
    }
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjAIr.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following

```
var body: some View {
    TextField("url", text: Binding(
        get: { self.queryItem.value ?? ""},
        set: { self.queryItem.value = $0 } )
    )
}
```